# ExpressJS not getting shown on browser

Tags: express

```
const express = require("express"); const app = express(); const
port = 3000;  

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{ 
res.send("This is homepage of my first express app with Harry"); 
});

app.listen(port, ()=>{
console.log(`The application started successfully on port ${port}`);
});
```

tried a many localhost 8000 3000 8080 but not getting anything.
Browser page in showing page did'nt found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, if it doesn't work, maybe try changing the port to 8000 or something, if that doesn't work get back to me as it could be a problem with your actual computer.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const PORT = 3000; // Try changing to 8000 if it doesn't work

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('This is homepage of my first express app with Harry')
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
```

Comment: I have tried many but it did'nt work., just it work sometime rearly on 3000 after reloading it 8 to 10 times on crome and even it is not working with postman.

Comment: still I am getting local host did'nt send any data.

Comment: Looking at what you're saying, I think it could be that your firewall could be interfering, maybe do some research into that. Have you got all of your dependencies installed? and how are you starting the app? (Checkout here for more info on firewall: https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/localhost-refused-to-connect-error)

Comment: Also make sure you're visiting http:// and not https://

Comment: thanks Fabien Brocklesby, I got the solution for my problem just I have replaced localhost with 127.0.0.1 and the things got fixed.

Comment: If you know the reason behind that please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This site can’t provide a secure connectionlocalhost sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR